# Can a Plugin Override New User Default Role Type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, user-roles

I'm making a plugin that creates user accounts. Is there a way I can create new users that get the role that I (the plugin developer) tell them to, as opposed to making them all the default new user role. I want to make new users a role type that is defined by my plugins parent plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `user_registration` action to set a custom role directly after wp_insert_user() has been called.

```
add_action('user_register', 'foo_set_new_user_role', 9999, 1);
function foo_set_new_user_role($user_id){
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role('your_new_role');
}
```

You can also use the action `profile_update` for just that, profile updates. It takes two parameters `$user_id` and `$old_user_data`.

Hope this helps you out.